# How to explicitly call a writer instance for a particular Rails method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So when it comes to Rails 6+ and multiple databases, I'm completely aware of this method:

```
    ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :writing) do
       # some write action to the database
    end
```

However, is it possible to just simply define particular methods that should use the writer database instance at the very top of the controller? For example:

```
class InvitedUsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :writing) do
      render '/invited_users/index'
    end
  end
```

In the index page, there's just simply a form but, due to the way it works with Devise, there is an INSERT statement from Devise that inserts a record into the sessions table, so this needs to be connected to the writer database.

Is there a way to say something like:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :writing) only: [show]
```

or anything like that?

Comment: Hi again :)  Even if you could do that, you're going to be eliminating the whole reason for having the read replica.  I'd definitely stick to just wrapping the devise method, so the rest of your reads are going to the replica.

Comment: Yeah I was just trying to see if there's a way to create it only for custom methods that use GET, but I definitely agree on wrapping the specific line with it.

Comment: This one should partly help: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5133#issuecomment-650728884